# How is a hyperledger fabric blockchain stored on a PC?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to get my head around blockchain and I'm finding it difficult to get a straight forward answer to this. Say I create a web application that interacts with a blockchain. A user opens my web app, logs in and uses that web application and so a transaction occurs and a new block is added to the chain. How is that blockchain stored on their PC, since the point of blockchain is that it is stored on every participating node? In what format is it stored?

Answer (score 2):

Your web application will interact with the blockchain as a client (likely using one of the Hyperledger Fabric SDKs).  The "blocks" will be stored on one or more peer nodes (depending on how many peers are connected to a given channel) not on your client nor on the server hosting your web application.

I'd recommend looking at [this](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/txflow.html) to understand the overall transaction flow and [this](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ledger.html) to understand the ledger.